# JS and onchange event in html form

Tags: javascript, forms, scripting, textbox, onchange

My code error is pretty obvious but I can´t see it.

It's very simple my form ask the `height` and `weight` and **calculate** the `corporal mass index` the user input height in meters and convert to inches (function works ok) 

input kilos and convert to pounds (works ok too) but in this process must calculate the index and write it in another textbox. that's my problem!

What am I doing wrong??? heres my code:

```js
      function myFunctionmts() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mters");
        var y = document.getElementById("inches");
        y.value = ((x.value*100)/2.54).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("mters").value=x.value;
        document.getElementById("inches").value=y.value;
      }
     </script>
     <script>
      function myFunctionkg() {
        var i = document.getElementById("imc");
        var p = document.getElementById("inches");
        var x = document.getElementById("kilos");
        var z = document.getElementById("pounds");
        var step1 = 0;
        var step2 = 0;
        var step3 = 0;
        z.value = (x.value/.454).toFixed(2);
        libras.value=z.value;
        document.getElementById("pounds").value=z.value;
        step1.value = z.value*703;
        step2.value = step1.value/p.value;
        step3.value = (step2.value/p.value).toFixed(1);
        document.getElementById("imc").value=step3.value
      }
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="#"> 
     <input type="text" name="mters" id="mters" required onchange="myFunctionmts()">
     <input type="text" name="inches" id="inches" placeholder="Inches" readonly>
     <input type="text" name="kilos" id="kilos" required onchange="myFunctionkg()">
     <input type="text" name="pounds" id="pounds" placeholder="Pounds" readonly>
     <input type="text" name="imc" id="imc" readonly>
     <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

Comment: You have typos. Change all `step1.value`, `step2.value` & `step3.value` to just `step1`, `step2` & `step3`. Those are just variables not dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="POST" action="#">
      <label for="mters">meter</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="mters"
        id="mters"
        required
        onchange="myFunctionmts()"
      />
      <label for="inches">inches</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="inches"
        id="inches"
        placeholder="Inches"
        readonly
      />
      <label for="kilos">kilos</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="kilos"
        id="kilos"
        required
        onchange="myFunctionkg()"
      />
      <label for="pounds">pounds</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="pounds"
        id="pounds"
        placeholder="Pounds"
        readonly
      />
      <label for="imc">imc</label>
      <input type="text" name="imc" id="imc" readonly />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function myFunctionmts() {
  var x = document.getElementById('mters');
  var y = document.getElementById('inches');
  y.value = ((x.value * 100) / 2.54).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('mters').value = x.value;
  document.getElementById('inches').value = y.value;
}

function myFunctionkg() {
  var imc = document.getElementById('imc'); // mass index
  var inches = document.getElementById('inches'); //
  var kilos = document.getElementById('kilos');
  var pounds = document.getElementById('pounds'); // pounds
  var step1 = 0;
  var step2 = 0;
  var step3 = 0;
  pounds.value = (+kilos.value / 0.454).toFixed(2);

  // undefined error here, what is this libras all about ???
  // libras.value = z.value;

  step1 = +pounds.value * 703;
  step2 = +step1 / +inches.value;
  step3 = (+step2 / +inches.value).toFixed(1);
  console.log(step3);
  imc.value = step3;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: WOWWW.... thanks.. work excelent!! you teach me the details i miss..tnx a lot

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.